# sed replace capture group with new string

Tags: regex, awk, sed

i have this string in file :

```
def code = project.hasProperty('versionName') ? versionName : "444444"
```

i like to replace only the 444444 with 55555

i tried :

```
sed  -E 's/versionName.*\"(.+)\"/55555/' my.gradle
```

but its result:

```
def code = project.hasProperty('55555
```

what I'm doing wrong, what is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown sample in GNU `sed`(should work for NON GNU `sed` also).

```
sed -E 's/(.*versionName : ")[0-9]+(.*)/\155555\2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `sed`'s `-E` option to enable ERE in code. Then using `sed`'s substitution option to make substitution. Using `sed`'s capability to store matched regex in temp buffer memory(wherever we use `(....)` with a regex in `sed` it keeps that value safe for each iteration wise and we can access those values by `1`,`2` and so on depending upon what is the number of `(....)` after `s` option). First regex matches everything till `versionName : "` then it looks for digits(which are not stored in memory), then saving rest of the line in 2nd temp memory value. While performing substitution simply mentioning `\1` to get first matched part and putting new value then placing `\2` to access 2nd stores value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution using `awk`:

```
awk -F 'versionName[ \t]*:[ \t]*' '{$2 = "versionName : \"55555\""} 1' file
```

```
def code = project.hasProperty('versionName') ?  versionName : "55555"
```